# Hubspot form embed onFormReady function from hbspt.forms.create TypeError: e.serializeArray is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, hubspot

I am trying to serialize an array for inputs in the Hubspot form to add or change cookies, but I keep getting the error `onFormReady function from hbspt.forms.create TypeError: e.serializeArray is not a function` and I don't know what to do. I am trying to not use jQuery, what can I use to replace it?

```
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
  region: "",
  portalId: "",
  formId: "",
  redirectUrl: "/thank-you/",
  onFormReady: function(e){
    e.serializeArray().map(x=>{
      let cookie_val = Cookies.get(x.name)
      if (cookie_val && cookie_val != ''){
        e.find('input[name="'+x.name+'"]').val(cookie_val).change();
      }
    })
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/building-blocks/forms#using-the-form-embed-code), `onFormReady` returns `form` object. It is not an array, so you can try to serialize inputs:

```
  onFormReady: function(e){
    e.find('input').serializeArray().map(x=>{
      let cookie_val = Cookies.get(x.name)
      if (cookie_val && cookie_val != ''){
        e.find('input[name="'+x.name+'"]').val(cookie_val).change();
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Just gave it a try and it says that find is not a function now. "hbspt.forms.create TypeError: e.find is not a function"

Comment: could you make `console.log(e)` please?

Comment: Isn't serializeArray only available if you use jQuery? I would like to not use jQuery.

Comment: Yes, but it seems the callback already returns jQuery object, so you can use it's method without using jQuery directly. On the other hand, if you receive such errors, it can be plain JS object.

Comment: Got it, yes. You are right. I need to rework this.